# videoJS: mouseTimeDisplay $(selector, contextopt) method example

Tags: javascript, dom, video.js, selectors-api

Looking at the documentation for videoJS for the [mouseTimedDisplay](https://docs.videojs.com/mousetimedisplay) and trying to understand it better.

How to I use the `$` selector?

(Thinking I then can avoid using `document.querySelector` to get elements/components.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a wrapper around `querySelector` that will search the component's element by default, unless a different starting element is given as a starting element.

Given the standard controls, `player.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.mouseTimeDisplay.$('div')` would return the inner div (with the `vjs-time-tooltip` class) of the MouseTimeDisplay component.

```
<div class="vjs-mouse-display">
  <div class="vjs-time-tooltip" aria-hidden="true"></div>
</div>
```

If you wanted the component's element (with `vjs-mouse-display`), you just use `el()`.

You'd mostly use it when creating/extending custom player components.

Comment: Thanks a lot @misterben - how did you know the "trail" to mouseTimeDisplay goes like `player.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.mouseTimeDisplay`? Are you using any type autosuggestion?

Comment: A browser dev console would autocomplete. That 'trail' will exist in a player with the defaults, but it's possible for some controls to be removed in player setup options. Depending on what you are trying to do there may be a better option to select the component.